# Flink ParquetAvroWriters giving cast ERROR

Tags: apache-flink, avro, parquet

I have written a sample code to write stream to parquet format after reading GenericRecord from Kafka

```
 Properties config = new Properties();
        config.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        config.setProperty("group.id", "1");
        config.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        String schemaRegistryUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8081";

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        File file = new File(EventProcessor.class.getClassLoader().getResource("event.avsc").getFile());
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(file);

        DataStreamSource<GenericRecord> input = env
                .addSource(
                        new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<GenericRecord>("event_new",
                                new KafkaGenericAvroDeserializationSchema(schemaRegistryUrl),
                                config).setStartFromEarliest());


        Path path = new Path("/tmp");

        final StreamingFileSink sink = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat
                (path, ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord(schema)).build();

        input.addSink(sink);
```

When I am running this code I am getting the error :

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getField(GenericData.java:697)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeRecordFields(AvroWriteSupport.java:188)
```

I am not able to understand what is wrong. Please help me to understand and resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that your event.avsc does not match the records stored in Kafka. It's finding a string, where it expects a record.

If you add the schema and an example record from Kafka (for example printed with console-consumer), then I could help more.

Comment: I have resolved it . its due to the wrong schema only.